# Which one is a correct usage of "-ing form"?

Tags: grammar

There are two examples

> Paying the enrollment fee by bank transfer this afternoon, she secures her seat for the three-day acting workshop in July.
>
> She paid the enrollment fee by bank transfer this afternoon, securing her seat for the three-day acting workshop in July.

I learned that "-ing" can be used for the earlier action when one action happens before another action.

Paying the fee happened before securing a seat.

So I assumed that the first example is the right one.

If someone let me know whether it is right or wrong, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Both of them are correct, they just mean slightly different things.  The first one is in the present tense, and says that she secures her seat by paying.  The second one is in the past tense, and says that her action of paying secured her seat.

Comment: It's the same as the difference between *Stretching her arms, she yawns*, and *She stretched her arms, yawning.* Both perfectly valid, and to all intents and purposes they mean exactly the same thing (except one's present tense and the other's past tense). The idea that the sequence in which the actions are reported has any implications for the sequence in which they actually *happened* is simply mistaken. In both my example and OP's, the words themselves carry the strong implication that both things happen at the same time (or are at least inextricably linked as a "combined" action).